# merge two dataframe based on intersection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have two dataframes df1 and df2

df1:

```
categories ; 
['hello','world']
['gogo','albert']
['dodo']
```

df2:

```
categories ; 
['hello','world']
['albert']
['dodji']
```

i want to have as result only lines of df1  based on :
if the intersection of df1 and df2 is true == keep this kine of df1 :
for example for our case we will have :

df_all:

```
categories ; 
['hello','world']
['gogo','albert']
```

because the intersection of  ['hello','world'] of df1 and  ['hello','world'] of df2 is true
and the intersection of ['gogo','albert'] and ['albert'] is true
so we keep those lines of df1

Comment: Intersection is not a boolean property, do you mean if the intersection size is greater than zero?

Comment: yes exactly thats iwant

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas isn't optimised for Series consisting of lists. I think the best solution is just to use Python sets and check length is nonzero, then use that to mask `df1`:

```
# Set up data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'categories': [['hello','world'],['gogo','albert'],['dodo']]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'categories': [['hello','world'],['albert'],['dodji']]})

# Solution
mask = [len(set(a).intersection(b)) > 0 
        for (a,b) in zip(df1.categories, df2.categories)]
df1.loc[mask]
```

Output:

```
    categories
0   [hello, world]
1   [gogo, albert]
```